# Celery periodic task prevent missing objs

Tags: celery, celerybeat

I have a reminder model -

```py
class Reminder(models.Model):
    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        CALL = "Call"
        WHATSAPP = "WhatsApp"
        SMS = "SMS"
        EMAIL = "Email"

    workspace = models.ForeignKey(
        "workspaces.Workspace", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reminders"
    )

    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=Types.choices, null=False, blank=False
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    due_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    remind_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    data = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=dict)

    completed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

To send notification for a reminder I use a periodic task that is run every 10 mins and schedules a task for all those reminder's whose remind_datetime is in the next 10 mins -

```py
@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def schedule_reminders(self):
    now = timezone.now()

    next_run_at = now + timedelta(seconds=SCHEDULE_REMINDERS_INTERVAL)

    due_reminders = Reminder.objects.filter(
        completed_at__isnull=True,
        remind_datetime__lte=next_run_at,
    )

    for reminder in due_reminders:
        schedule_reminder.delay(reminder_id=reminder.id)
```

The issue is I am concerned about how some reminders may not get scheduled because of some millisecs

Say, I receive `schedule_reminders` task at `6:00.00`, then inside the task `now=6:00.10`, so `next_run_at = 6:10.10`
Now if there is a reminder whose `remind_datetime=6:00.05`. Then this reminder will never be scheduled.